# How to get the Admin code of an option from an attribute? REST API

Tags: magento2, attributes, api, rest-api, admin-panel

I have a problem, and I want you to give me a light at the end of the tunnel.
I am doing an **integration REST** and need to get some information from the **options** of an **attribute**, in the **admin panel** I have 4 options being them. Among them **Admin**, I am using the following method to return the options.
`rest/V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}/options`
`rest/V1/products/attributes/tamanho/options`

Was the only method I found in https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html which made sense, but the return only comes the **option code** and the **Default Store View**, the **Admin** does not appear, how I get the code Admin?

I would like to receive in return for example:

```
{
   "label": "L/XL descr",
   "value": "519",
   "admin_code": "LXL",
   "is_default": true
}
```

Prints
[image: Options in Admin panel]
[image: Method response]

Answer (score 0):

To return the admin values scope try passing "all" in your rest request. For example:

> /rest/**all**/V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}/options

Or in your case:

> /rest/**all**/V1/products/attributes/tamanho/options